# Math modeling of inventory optimization using cplex

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, cplex, pyomo

[image: Math model]

I'm trying to solve this using CPLEX using pyomo framework. My code is as follow

```py
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
import numpy as np

model=pyo.ConcreteModel() 
T=10
cap=1000
inflow=500
outflow=250
demand=300
cost=25
model.inv=pyo.Var(range(1,T+1),within=Integers, bounds=(0,np.inf))
inv=model.inv

model.c0=pyo.Constraint(expr=inv[0]==300)
model.c1=pyo.ConstraintList()
for t in range(0,(T)):
    model.c1.add(expr=inv[t]<=cap)
model.c2=pyo.ConstraintList()
for t in range(0,(T)):
    model.c2.add(expr=inv[t]+inflow-outflow<=inv[t+1])
model.c3=pyo.ConstraintList()
for t in range(0,(T)):
    model.c3.add(inv[t]>=demand)


model.obj=pyo.Objective(expr=sum(inv[t]*cost for t in range(1,(T+1))),sense=minimize)

opt=SolverFactory('cplex')
opt.solve(model)

model.pprint()

for t in range(1,T+1):
    print(pyo.value(inv[t]))
print(pyo.value(model.obj))
```

The error states that "Index '0' is not valid for indexed component 'inv'"
Any help is much appreciated

To get the minimum carrying cost of all the inventory

Comment: You need to describe the single-letter variables in your model image; there is no correspondence between them and your code.

Comment: Do u mean a decision variable?

Answer (score 0):

I would turn

```
model.inv=pyo.Var(range(1,T+1),within=Integers, bounds=(0,np.inf))
```

into

```
model.inv=pyo.Var(range(0,T+1),within=Integers, bounds=(0,np.inf))
```

Comment: Tried the same but no luck as the error now shows
ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object inv[1]

Comment: In « for t in range(1,T+1):
    print(pyo.value(inv[t])) » turn 1 to 0 and T+1 to T